# What exactly was in Pandora's Box?

Tags: greek, pandora

So, only Hope remained in that box. And a whole bunch of bad stuff came out.

But, what *exactly* was in there? I'm looking for the greek proper names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Theoi](http://www.theoi.com/Daimon/Keres.html) suggests that the overall name for the evil spirits might be Keres:

> The Keres may have been the evil spirits released from Pandora's jar to plague mankind. Hesiod mentions them indirectly in his account of the episode. He describes these spirits as ***[kakoi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BA%CF%8C%CF%82)*** (evils), ***[nosoi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BD%CF%8C%CF%83%CE%BF%CF%82)*** (sicknesses and plagues) and ***[lugra](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BB%CF%85%CE%B3%CF%81%CF%8C%CF%82)*** (banes).

They are mentioned both above and within the passage Yannis cites:

> "For ere this [the opening of Pandora's jar] the tribes of men lived on earth remote and free from ills (***kakoi***) and hard toil (***ponoi***) and heavy sickness (***nosoi***) which bring the ***Keres*** (Fates) upon men; for in misery men grow old quickly. But the woman took off the great lid of the jar (*pithos*) with her hands and scattered all these and her thought caused sorrow and mischief to men. Only ***[Elpis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%90%CE%BB%CF%80%CE%AF%CF%82)*** (Hope) remained there in an unbreakable home within under the rim of the great jar, and did not fly out at the door; for ere that, the lid of the jar stopped her, by the will of Aigis-holding Zeus who gathers the clouds. But the rest, countless plagues (***lugra***), wander amongst men; for earth is full of evils and the sea is full. Of themselves diseases (*nosoi*) come upon men continually by day and by night, bringing mischief to mortals silently; for wise Zeus took away speech from them. So is there no way to escape the will of Zeus."

Note that this is a fair degree of leeway in translating *kakoi*, *nosoi*, *ponoi* and *lugra*, thus no single translation is definitive.

Answer (score 5):

Not entirely sure what exactly you are looking for, but "a whole bunch of bad stuff" is actually very close to how Hesiod describes the ills that escaped the jar (Works and Days, lines 95-105):

> ἀλλὰ γυνὴ χείρεσσι πίθου μέγα πῶμ᾽ ἀφελοῦσα
>   ἐσκέδασ᾽: ἀνθρώποισι δ᾽ ἐμήσατο κήδεα λυγρά.
>   μούνη δ᾽ αὐτόθι Ἐλπὶς ἐν ἀρρήκτοισι δόμοισιν
>   ἔνδον ἔμιμνε πίθου ὑπὸ χείλεσιν, οὐδὲ θύραζε
>   ἐξέπτη: πρόσθεν γὰρ ἐπέλλαβε πῶμα πίθοιο
>   αἰγιόχου βουλῇσι Διὸς νεφεληγερέταο.
>   ἄλλα δὲ μυρία λυγρὰ κατ᾽ ἀνθρώπους ἀλάληται:
>   πλείη μὲν γὰρ γαῖα κακῶν, πλείη δὲ θάλασσα:
>   νοῦσοι δ᾽ ἀνθρώποισιν ἐφ᾽ ἡμέρῃ, αἳ δ᾽ ἐπὶ νυκτὶ
>   αὐτόματοι φοιτῶσι κακὰ θνητοῖσι φέρουσαι
>   σιγῇ, ἐπεὶ φωνὴν ἐξείλετο μητίετα Ζεύς.
>   οὕτως οὔτι πη ἔστι Διὸς νόον ἐξαλέασθαι.

In Hugh G. Evelyn-White's translation, the passage is:

> But the woman took off the great lid of the jar with her hands and scattered, all these and her thought caused sorrow and mischief to men. Only Hope remained there in an unbreakable home within under the rim of the great jar, and did not fly out at the door; for ere that, the lid of the jar stopped her, by the will of Aegis-holding Zeus who gathers the clouds. But the rest, countless plagues, wander amongst men; for earth is full of evils, and the sea is full. Of themselves diseases come upon men continually by day and by night, bringing mischief to mortals silently; for wise Zeus took away speech from them.

Comment: As Yannis comments, nothing is mentioned specifically with the exception of Hope.  Thus *Elpis* is the only proper name found in the text.  (You will note that Ἐλπὶς is capitalized in the Greek text.)

Comment: @DukeZhou Of course, the original Greek was all in capitals, so it's this translator's guess that Hesiod meant the person Ἐλπὶς and not hope in general.